# Android Alert style overriding React Native Development Menu

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, themes, alert

I am trying to style the Android alert dialog in React Native.  What I've done is this:

1. I've added a special style for the App Theme:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

2. That style looks as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#0078D4</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0078D4</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0078D4</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now, when I trigger the Alert in React Native, this looks great!  However, when I try to pull up the debug menu to enable reloading/debugging/etc., it just looks blank:

[image: Blank debug menu on React Native.]

Can anyone tell me if:

1. There's a better way to do this styling so that it doesn't impact the developer menu
2. There's a way to modify my existing custom style to re-light the developer menu in the app?

I have verified that removing the style fixes the issue, so this is the cause.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution for this, how to edit there alert component with out impacting the debug menu ?